# Sorting array in chunks doesn't work

Tags: javascript

Seemed as a simple task, but doesn't work. I have an array of known length (say 9) and a chunk size (say 3). Array is always dividable by that chunk, no need to test. At first tried:

```js
const chunked = [];
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for(let i=0; i<3; i++) { 
    chunked[i] = arr.slice(i*3, 3);
}

console.log(chunked);
```

But then realised that `slice()` probably overwrites its input, so:

```js
const chunked = [];
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for(let i=0; i<3; i++) { 
    let temp = arr.slice();
    chunked[i] = temp.slice(i*3, 3);
}

console.log(chunked);
```

But still only first chunk is being created... Where is my error?

Comment: The second argument to `slice` isn’t a length, but the end index.

Comment: Oh yes, wasnt aware of that. This works `for(let i=0; i<3; i++) { let temp = res.slice();
    res2[i] = temp.slice(i*3, (i+1)*3);
}` Many thanks

Comment: I know about similar SO questions, but these seemd too complicated. That way in my comment seems simplier and easier to understand

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> The slice() method returns a shallow copy of a portion of an array
>   into a new array object selected from begin to end (end not included).
>   The original array will not be modified.

```
arr.slice([begin[, end]])
```

You can loop from 0 until the length of array and increment by chunck size.

like:

```js
const chunked = [];
const chuckSize = 3;
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for (let i = 0; i < arr.length; i += chuckSize) {
  chunked.push(arr.slice(i, i + chuckSize));
}

console.log(chunked);
```

Answer (score 2):

Try following

```js
const chunked = [];
const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];

for(let i=0; i<3; i++) { 
    let temp = arr.slice();
    
    chunked[i] = temp.slice(i*3, (i+1)*3); // Need to set appropriate begin and end
}

console.log(chunked);
```

For reference, [Array.slice](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0):

The second parameter for `slice` is the end index (not the length) as you may be assuming. You can find the docs [here](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/slice)

Answer (score 0):

The function `slice` takes parameter as `slice(firstIndex, lastIndex + 1)`

Please use the following code:

```js
 const chunked = [];
    const arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9];
    
    for(let i=0; i<3; i++) { 
        chunked[i] = arr.slice(i*3, i*3 + 3);
    }
    
    console.log(chunked);
```